# Ajax Post (Model binded) passing null to the controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making an AJAX POST request to the controller (ASP.NET Core MVC), yet the value for the parameter is coming through as null. I tried several solutions given on StackOverflow. But, I couldn't correct it. Please help.

My view collects class fees information. There may have more than one payment.

```js
$(function () {
           $('#sendSlip').click(function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               let fees = new Array(); //To store payment info
               let tb = $('#feesTable:eq(0) tbody');
//Collecting info of each payment
               tb.find("tr").each(function () {
                   let row = $(this);
                   let fee = {};
                   if (row.find('input:checkbox:first').is(':checked')) {
                       fee.ClassId = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                       fee.FeeId = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                       fee.Amount = row.find(".fee").html();
                       fee.Month = row.find(".month").html();
                       fees.push(fee);
                   }
               });
//Arranging data to send to controller
               var data = { 
                   fees: fees,
                   Bank: $(".bank").val(),
                   PaidAmount : $(".amount").val(),
                   PaidDate : $(".date").val()
           };
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("StudentPayment_Create", "StudentPayment")',
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': gettoken() },
                    data: //{ data: JSON.stringify(data) },
                    JSON.stringify(data) ,
                })
                 
            });
        });
```

Model

```cs
public class StudentPaymentSlipVM
{
    public StudentPaymentPaidClassVM fees { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaidDate { get; set; }
    public int PaidAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```cs
public ActionResult StudentPayment_Create([FromBody] List<StudentPaymentSlipVM> data)
{
---
}
```

Object details at runtime
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From your attached screenshot for data to be passed to the controller, the data's structure was unmatched with the data model the controller expected.

**Assume the data structure for the front-end is correct**.

Controller should expect that the **received data is a `StudentPaymentSlipVM` object**. While in the `StudentPaymentSlipVM` object, the **`fees` is a `StudentPaymentPaidClassVM` array**.

> Model

```cs
public class StudentPaymentSlipVM
{
    public List<StudentPaymentPaidClassVM> fees { get; set; }
    public string Bank { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaidDate { get; set; }
    public int PaidAmount { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller

```cs
public ActionResult StudentPayment_Create([FromBody] StudentPaymentSlipVM data)
{

}
```

While from your JQuery part, make sure that your data object to be passed to API must be matched with the data type as your model in the back-end.

```js
var data = { 
    fees: fees,
    Bank: $(".bank").val(),
    PaidAmount : parseInt($(".amount").val()),
    PaidDate : $(".date").val()
};
```

Comment: Thank you Yong Shun. May know how can I correct it? I am not sure how to do it. So if you can pls explain.

Comment: Hi, check out the answer I posted. The answer (for Model and Controller) is based on your data object (screenshot).

Comment: Yes. I corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to pass my data to controller by binding to a ViewModel (StudentPaymentSlipVM) which has all required definitions. But I couldn't do it. So I changed the way and pass my object to Controller as following way now it is working.
And also I would like to thanks Yong Shun.

1. Changed the JQuery code

```
 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: '@Url.Action("action", "controller")',                    
                     headers: { 'RequestVerificationToken': gettoken() },
                     data: dataObj,
                 })
```

2. I changed the Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult StudentPayment_Create(List<StudentPaymentPaidClassVM> Fees,  string Bank, decimal PaidAmount, DateTime PaidDate)
        {
.....
}
```